# Fetch a list of values from map

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a map with key a `String` and `List<String>` as value. I want to fetch a list of all values against all keys from that map using Java 8. My method gives me a list of values. I am wrongly mapping all values to 'List' and underlying elements of my list are being converted to a single object. I want all of them as individual elements of a list.

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
List<String> myList = map.values().stream().map(List::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use:

```
map.values().forEach(myList::addAll);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. No need of explicitly using stream. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatMap` to obtain a `Stream` of all the `String`s of all the `List<String>` values of the `Map`:

```
List<String> myList = map.values()
                         .stream()
                         .flatMap(List::stream)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that the `List` may contain duplicates. If you wish to avoid that, add `distinct()` after `.flatMap()`.